# How to clear BLE cache in iOS, connected Bluetooth device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

We are working Bluetooth device for connection perform the read/write operations. Bluetooth services Not going to update once we connect Bluetooth device. If we have added new read/write BLE service characteristics then we need to reset iPhone.

**We are doing the below steps**

Initially we connect to Bluetooth Device. we are perform the READ and WRITE all services. But if Bluetooth device firmware version Updated and this version we have added new BLE service characteristics, in that case I am not able to get new BLE service in iOS device iPhone and iPad.

I have to reset all device and then i can get new updated services from Bluetooth Device.

How we can fix this issue on iOS swift.

*Thanks in advance !*

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by providing the *service changed characteristic* on your BLE device. Take the [Accessory Design Guidelines](https://www.bluetooth.com/wp-content/uploads/attachments/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf) as a reference. It states at 11.12.2 (emphasis mine):

> The accessory **must** implement the Service Changed characteristic only
> if the accessory has the ability to **change its services during its
> lifetime**.

Simply implementing this will force your iPhone and iPad to always read the services and characteristics from the device instead from the cache. This is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/120689).

Other than resetting your devices Bluetooth adapter I am not aware of another way to reset the cache.

Comment: Note that if the devices are bonded, the central may use cached services. In that case, the peripheral shall use this characteristic to indicate what range has been updated.